# How can I round a decimal to the nearest even number in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, rounding

I need to round a decimal in a sql query on Oracle 10g to the nearest even number.
If the number is even, it should be returned. If the number is odd, the next even number should be returned.

This is what I want:
8.05 should return 8.06, 3.48 should return 3.48

How can I do this?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: The concepts "even" and "odd" are only applicable to integers; 8.06 is not an "even number" in other words. Thus to get the effect you want, you can scale the value to an integer and then mask off the low bit, then scale it back. I don't know Oracle SQL so I don't know how to do that or if it's even possible in a simple expression.

Comment: Always 2 decimal places?

Comment: What the logic behind this operation 8.05 ~ 8.06 ? Do 8.03 should be 8.04 or may it be 8.06 ?

Comment: Yes - the number is always 2 decimal places. 8.03 should return 8.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to round e.g. to the second decimal even digit, you can do something like that: `select round(3.43 / 0.02, 0) * 0.02;` that will produce `3.44`.

This can be extended as you wish: e.g. first decimal digit which is multiple of 3: `select round(3.5452234 / 0.3, 0) * 0.3;` will give `3.6`.

Comment: But for this solution the 3.48 is 3.4 not 3.48 as in question.

Comment: select round(3.48 / 0.02, 0) * 0.02; #=> 3.48

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand the logic of incorrectly rounding numbers. Additionally, this cannot easily because you aren't dealing with integers. However, if you really need to, I would suggest following something like this pseudo-code.

```
if ((num / 2) * 2 = num) {
    return // number is even
    }
else {
    num = num + .01 // this assumes you are only working with two decimal points.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle Database 18c you can use `round_ties_to_even`. This rounds the least significant digit for values at the half-way point to the nearest even number.

The first parameter is the value to round. The second is the number of significant digits to round to:

- Zero (the default) => integer rounding
- Positive values => number of digits to the *right* of the decimal point
- Negative values => number of digits to the *left* of the decimal point

If all the values have (at most) two decimal places, you can round the hundredths to the nearest even by

- Rounding to two decimal places
- Adding five thousands (0.005) to the input so all values are at the midpoint

For example:

```
with rws as (
  select 8.04 n from dual union all
  select 8.05 n from dual union all
  select 8.06 n from dual union all
  select 8.07 n from dual union all
  select 3.48 n from dual 
)
  select n, round_ties_to_even ( n + 0.005, 2 )
  from   rws;
  
         N ROUND_TIES_TO_EVEN(N+0.005,2)
---------- -----------------------------
      8.04                          8.04
      8.05                          8.06
      8.06                          8.06
      8.07                          8.08
      3.48                          3.48
```